# RE: implemrnting match range {m,n} in NFA?

Tags: regex, range, implementation, nfa

I was able to using NFA to implement + and ? and ., but I'm having hard time figuring out how to implement match-range {m,n}. F.e.:

```
 a{1,3}
 (ab){2,4}
 .{,3}
```

and so on.
Is there a way to implement it with pure NFA ?

If not what other advise can you give me ?

I used this as a starting point :

https://deniskyashif.com/2019/02/17/implementing-a-regular-expression-engine/

Comment: Same as `a(a(a?)?)`, `(ab)(ab)(ab(ab)?)?`, and so on.

Comment: Also a{1,3} is equivalent to (a|aa|aaa).

Comment: ha.. a bit  hairy, but probably will work ...  if I use it with bigger numbers the nfa will grow alot ... thanks for the ideas